# Deleting a record older than 6 years in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been trying to delete a record that is older than 5 years. I am using sql developer and using this query:

```
DELETE FROM TBLPATIENT WHERE DATEADD(year, 4, DISCHARGE_DATE) < getdate()
```

'discharge_date' is the column name with date data type. The command is giving me this error,

> Error at Command Line : 1 Column : 69 Error report - SQL Error:
>   ORA-00904: "GETDATE": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Its like many days now, I'm struggling with same problem, altering many commands to delete a record, but nothing is working out for me..

Comment: `Dateadd` and `getdate()` are `Sql server` functions. Search for equivalent in oracle

Comment: You want to use `SYSDATE`. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions172.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this in Oracle you'd use:

```
DELETE FROM TBLPATIENT
  WHERE DISCHARGE_DATE + INTERVAL '4' YEAR < SYSDATE;
```

It might be more efficient to avoid adding a literal to every DISCHARGE_DATE in TBLPATIENT; thus, the following might be worth a try:

```
DELETE FROM TBLPATIENT
  WHERE DISCHARGE_DATE < SYSDATE - INTERVAL '4' YEAR;
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: It says, delete dependencies first. Which means I have to delete other things first, but I want my command to do it for me, like delete dependencies and then delete the record.

Comment: In that case you should set up foreign key constraints between your child and parent tables, with the "ON DELETE" action on the constraints set to "ON DELETE CASCADE". From your description of the issues you're facing it sounds like the constraints may already exist but that the delete action is set to "NO ACTION". Another possible approach would be to create a "BEFORE DELETE" trigger on TBLPATIENT in which you could code DELETE statements to delete from all the subordinate tables.